# Passing 2-D array of pair<int,float> to c dll from c#

Tags: c#, .net, c, dll, pinvoke

I am new to c# programming. I have a function in c which I want to call from a .NET interface. So I created a dll for this function. Everything worked  fine till this point.  This function takes an input argument which is array of array of pair:

```
typedef pair<int,float> Node;
typedef Node** DATA;
```

The function prototype for the c function is :

```
void Train(DATA X, float* Y, float* W);
```

In order to use this function in .NET interface, first i have to convert my data  which is in two array's into Node type. Something like :

```
DATA D = new Node*[2];
D[0] = new Node[5];
D[1] = new Node[2];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    D[0][i].first = i;
    D[0][i].second = i+5;
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
    D[1][i].first = i;
    D[1][i].second = i+5;
}
```

Now, i need help in defining this Node ( or pair) type in c# and then passing a reference to a 2-D array of of Node's to c dll.

Comment: The solution involves C++/CLI

Answer (score 0):

It depens on the memory layout of pair in c code, but you could define in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 4)]
public struct pair
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int first;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double second;
}
```

and use it like that:

```
    [DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    static extern void callMyDll(pair** mypair);
```

(pointers can be used c# using /unsafe option)

or

```
    [DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    static extern void callMyDll(pair[] mypair);
```

(this one copies managed memory to unmanaged memory using the memory mapping you specified via "MarshalAs" attributes => safer)

**edit:** avoid passing pointers as much as possible: address of objects instanciated in C# can change... or see ["fixed" keyword reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx)

**edit2:** if "pair" is a C++ class (with a virtual table) and not a structure, then you will have to prepend its members with a `void* vtableAddress;` in its C# definition.
See further documentation on virtual table mechanisms if you want to know why (used by C++ and almost any compiled languages using virtual calls)

Comment: This isn't it. We've got a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of Node. Going to be tricky from C#.